# Karaf Custom Distribution not adding features correctly

Tags: apache-karaf

I am trying to build a custom distribution of `Apache Karaf` following [this guide](http://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest-2.3.x/developers-guide/custom-distribution.html). I have few features I want to add to my distribution and for that I have modified the `pom.xml` file like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.karaf.tooling</groupId>
    <artifactId>features-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.4</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>add-features-to-repo</id>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>add-features-to-repo</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>mvn:org.apache.karaf.assemblies.features/standard/2.3.2/xml/features</descriptor>
                    <descriptor>mvn:org.apache.camel.karaf/apache-camel/2.12.3/xml/features</descriptor>
                    <descriptor>mvn:io.hawt/hawtio-karaf/1.2.3/xml/features</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
                <features>
                    <feature>camel-ftp</feature>
                    <feature>camel-sql</feature>
                    <feature>camel-blueprint</feature>
                    <feature>hawtio</feature>
                    <feature>webconsole</feature>
                </features>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

In addition, I have modified the file `org.apache.karaf.features.cfg` to reflect the new features:

```
#
# Comma separated list of features repositories to register by default
#
featuresRepositories=mvn:org.apache.karaf/apache-karaf/2.3.4/xml/features,mvn:org.apache.camel.karaf/apache-camel/2.12.3/xml/features,mvn:io.hawt/hawtio-karaf/1.2.3/xml/features

#
# Comma separated list of features to install at startup
#
featuresBoot=config,ssh,management,webconsole,camel-ftp,camel-blueprint,camel-sql,hawtio
```

Also, I want few jars installed by default and for that I have modified `bin.xml`:

```
<!-- Copy over jar files -->
<fileSet>
    <directory>lib/</directory>
    <includes>
        <include>lib1.jar</include>
        <include>lib2.jar</include>
    </includes>
    <outputDirectory>/lib/</outputDirectory>
</fileSet>
```

Once I have everything ready I run `mvn install` and I get my `tar.gz` file with my custom distribution that has the all files required inside. My problem comes when I start karaf and I run `features:list` and nothing is installed. Not even the default features that you have if you download the default distribution. What I am doing wrong? Do I need to change anything else?

My final goal is to have a custom distribution that has all the default features plus:

- Apache Camel
- Apache Camel Blueprint
- Apache Camel SQL
- Apache Camel FTP
- Hawtio
- Webconsole